# Trying to pass a column name as a parameter in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have columns in my table called store1, store2, etc,. If I make the call:

```
call storeinv(1);
```

I would like the routine to do:

```
select sum(store1) from inventory;
```

I'm having a really hard time passing the column name in a way that it won't be interpreted as a string. Does anyone know a workaround for this? Thanks. Here's my code so far:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `storeinv`(store int)

BEGIN
    prepare stmt1 from '(select sum(?) from inventory)';
    set @a = concat('store',store);
    execute stmt1 using @a;
END
```

Comment: How about sending the whole query as the procedure parameter like:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `storeinv`(query VARCHAR(1024))
and use it, prepare stmt1 from '(query)';

Comment: so you have columns in your table called `store1` `store2` and etc?

Comment: avisheks I'm not sure what you mean by using a query as a parameter. So when I call the procedure I would <code> call storeinv(select sum(store1) from inventory)</code> ?


@VladimirOselsky yes, that's correct. And the purpose of the function is to select the sum of a given column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing column name as parameter in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879772/passing-column-name-as-parameter-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do exactly what you want, however, the following might help assuming there is some limit on the number of store columns:

```
select sum(elt(?,store1,store2,store3,store4,store5...)) from inventory
```