# Passing column name as parameter in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
SELECT template_id as id FROM templates WHERE ? IN template_allowed_parent_templates
```

So I want to see if a given ID is in the column.
If not, how can I fix this with only MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as passing a column name as a parameter in MySQL (the question in the title), that's not possible in a SQL statement.  The *identifiers* in a SQL statement (e.g. the table names and column names) must be part of the SQL text. Those can't be passed in with a bind placeholder.

The `IN` comparison operator expects a list of values enclosed in parens, or a SELECT query enclosed in parens that returns a set of values.

It's not clear what you are attempting to do.

I suspect that `template_allowed_parent_templates` is a column in the table, and it contains a comma separated list of values. (shudder.)

I suspect you might be looking for the MySQL **`FIND_IN_SET`** string function, which will "search" a comma separated list for a particular value.

As a simple demonstration:

```
  SELECT FIND_IN_SET('5', '2,3,5,7')
       , FIND_IN_SET('4', '2,3,5,7')
```

The function returns a positive integer when the specified value is "found". You can make use of that function in a predicate, e.g.

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,template_allowed_parent_templates)
```

or

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( ? ,template_allowed_parent_templates)
```

(This works because in MySQL a positive integer is evaluated as TRUE in a boolean context.)

I'm only guessing at what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: You sir, you are my HERO!

Comment: Storing comma separated lists is an antipattern.  I recommend Bill Karwin's excellent book...  [SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557).  Chapter 2 "Jaywalking" covers this particular topic. (The entire chapter is available for preview from Amazon.)

Comment: Yeah... normally I would go for a second table with allowed_parents, But I thought it was a bit overkill just to achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify a bit more what you want to do?

From the query, it seems like you want to get all the template_id from templates, where some value is in the collection template_allowed_parent_templates. Where does passing column name as parameter come in?

Comment: Well, template_allowed_parent_templates is The column name

Comment: Ah, so you table looks something like this?

( template_id | template_allowed_parent_templates | .... )

In that case, you could do a sub-query to get all the values in it, but I don't see the point

SELECT template_id as id FROM templates WHERE ? IN (SELECT distinct template_allowed_parent_templates)

It makes more sense to just use a '=' insted of 'IN'. It would do the same thing as the other query if I'm not mistaken, except cleaner and more efficient.

A practicle example of what you want to achieve would be nice if this didn't answer your question :)

Comment: Yes indeed! and the template_allowed_parent_templates contains data like '0,5,9,6'. So I need to find the templates where template_allowed_parent_templates contains any given ID...

Comment: Oh, so "template_allowed_parent_templates" is a string containing ids?

In that case, you probably want "LIKE" to search the string. But you should really use another table for this relation.

so your table "templates": (template_id | ...) then another table "template_allowed_parent_templates": (template_id | template_id)

Then the query would be done with a join or sub-query.

Comment: Well, "like" is not an option... When allowed_templates contains 10 and ID 1 is given, it will also return all records with 10, 100, ...

Comment: Yes, that's right, but ultimately you should consider splitting the table into two tables as I suggested, which will give you more control and less problems in the long run :)