# Error MySQL in Go

Tags: mysql, sql, go, sql-update

This code is working:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("UPDATE `test` SET `score` = ? WHERE id = ?")
CheckErr(err)
_, err = stmt.Exec(value, id)
```

But when I change my code, it doesn't work:

```
stmt, err := db.Prepare("UPDATE `test` SET ? = ? WHERE id = ?")
CheckErr(err)
_, err = stmt.Exec("score", value, id)
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What does the error tell you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing column name as parameter in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879772/passing-column-name-as-parameter-in-mysql)

Comment: @Flimzy
It's too long!!

2018/08/28 15:24:54 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:21801: Error 1064: You have an
 error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL serve
r version for the right syntax to use near '? = ? WHERE id = ?' at line 1
goroutine 5 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc04204c960)
        C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1726 +0xd7
panic(0x67cae0, 0xc0420c2920)
        C:/Go/src/runtime/panic.go:502 +0x237
main.CheckErr(0x70e940, 0xc0420c2920)
        G:/Codes/GO/src/aHTTP/main.go:138 +0x51
main.MySQL()
        ............

Comment: What's too long?

Comment: @Flimzy
an error!

Comment: Include the error in your question. And also read it--amazingly, it actually explains the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better or worse, parameters can only be used for literal constants inside a query.  These are generally comparison values in the `where` clause, sometimes constants in the `select` or `set` clauses -- and less often in other parts of the query.

Identifiers are not literal constants.  In fact, none of the following are:

- database, table, and column names
- function names
- operators (such as `+`)
- keywords (such as `asc`/`desc` in `order by`)

Unfortunately, to implement these "dynamically", you need to munge the query string, by directly modifying the string.  That is rather yucky, but there no alternatively.

One of the benefits of this approach is that it allows the database to store and then re-use the query plan.  Eliminating the compilation phase can be an important performance gain for very fast queries.

EDIT:

I do not really know go, but the idea is:

```
sql := "UPDATE `test` SET [col] = ? WHERE id = ?"

sql = strings.replace(sql, "[col]", "score")

stmt, err := db.Prepare(sql)
CheckErr(err)
_, err = stmt.Exec(value, id)
```

In other words, directly change the query string for identifiers.  Continue to use parameters for values.

Comment: What I should doing now?

Answer (score 0):

You must need to mention column name in database update statement. without column name in set line of update query, it will not be prepared.

Comment: Am I should write for any update a func? Is there any way  to I write column name in
stmt.Exec("score", value, id)